# How do I change the module type in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created a project from maven using mvn idea:idea. I recreate the project whenever there is a significant change to the pom files.

Sometimes after recreating, when I open IntelliJ it tells me that the modules have an unknown type so they will be treated as Unknown Modules.

1. How do I changes these modules to be the proper type?
2. Can anyone direct me to documentation about how to specify the module type so that idea:idea will generate the modules properly?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mvn idea:idea generated projects are not supported, please use the built-in IDEA Maven support instead, it works much better and you have an option to import changed Maven projects automatically or manually.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try - I didn't realise idea:idea generated projects weren't supported. That might explain quite a lot...

Comment: This seems to work - there must be some problems in the Maven files as I'm still struggling to get it to work, but in principle it's working better than trying to use the idea:idea generated probject files. Thanks :)